# Firebase Cloud Messaging is successful when sent individually to a device but fails when sent in bulk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to engage my app users. I am successful when i am sending message to a individual device token.

```
<?php
$registrationIds = 'c1aZBUJBlXY:APA91bGCO0qXey7............';
$fields = array();
$fields['to'] = $$registrationIds;
$fields['notification'] = $msg;
?>
```

My device is receiving the message and when I read the curl result it shows :-

{"multicast_id":4961279489110672804,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1520286049798478%d85e42c1d85e42c1"}]}

I am happy for this response. But when I try to send the notifications to three device tokens (two of which are unregistered) as below:

```
<?php
$registrationIds = array();
$registrationIds[0] = 'c1aZBUJBlXY:APA91bGCO0qXey7....';// Same as previos one.
$registrationIds[1] = 'fCT0OGHDkv8:APA91bGReDDPLO.....';//unregistered token
$registrationIds[2] = 'dFRzNGTgvi8:APA91bFawERcaVX1r.....';//unregistered token

$fields = array();
$fields['registration_ids'] = $$registrationIds;
$fields['data'] = $msg;
?>
```

I get the following response :-

{"multicast_id":8151389096469325865,"success":1,"failure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1520286125422565%d85e42c1f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

But I don't receive any message on my device. Can anyone please tell me why i device is not receiving the notification despite FCM giving a success message.

Comment: i also tried with tha 'notification' attribute instead of 'data' in the second case but still I receive same success message for one device token but i don't receive any notification on my device.

Comment: sorry ... when I tried with 'notification' attribute i received the push message. But why should i get success message when i use 'data' attribute instead of 'notification' attribute.

Comment: Are you using data messages in your app? That data could be sent successfully, but if you aren't doing anything with it client-side, it would look like no message was received.

Comment: Thanks Jen for replying ... Now things are fine. As mentioned by you I found that the issue is at the client-side. Now the push notifications are working fine... :)